# How can I create wood text effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, cs6, effects

How can I create a wood text effect such as this logo using Photoshop CS6?

[image]

Comment: @Scott: I'm a newbie so I just wrote a brown text using a big font, and then applied Drop Shadow on it.

Comment: I don't meant to be rude, but a 10 second Google search for "Photoshop Wood Text tutorial" will result in literally **hundreds**, if not thousands, of tutorials. My point was that GD.SE is a not a "tutorials on demand" site. Please edit your answer to explain what you have tried and where it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

1. select the wood image
2. crop it
3. save as a pattern image: `edit` > `define pattern` and save button
4. open a new file
5. type a text
6. right click the text layer
7. select blending options
8. in that select pattern overlay
9. in that list select newly saved pattern
10. apply
11. apply some shadows if u need.....

Answer (score -1):

The best way to apply wood effect in text is make pattern from a wood image and use it as Smart Object in PS

Comment: Hi Mohatir! Welcome to GD.SE. We generally expect answers to include details, steps, and so on. There isn't much to add to this one, but keep it in mind for future answers :)